# In Laravel I'm having difficulty understanding the syntax required to iterate thru an array in my blade using @foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having issues reading through the following "$photos" array that I've passed from the controller to the blade.

```
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "destinationPath" => "images/"
    "filename" => "15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-34824.jpg"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "destinationPath" => "images/"
      "filename" => "15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-89914.jpg"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "destinationPath" => "images/"
      "filename" => "15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-30958.jpg"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "destinationPath" => "images/"
      "filename" => "15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-68870.jpg"
    ]
  ]
]
```

**If I call photos directly in the blade as follows it works to pull up the image:**

```
  <img class="img-fluid options-item" src="{{$path}}/{{ $photos[0]['destinationPath'] }}{{ $photos[0]['filename'] }}" alt="">
```

**but when I attempt to loop thru the array**

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++)
  <img class="img-fluid options-item" src="{{$path}}/{{ $photos[$i]['destinationPath'] }}{{ $photos[$i]['filename'] }}" alt="">
@endfor
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined index: destinationPath (View: C:\Apache24\htdocs\collection\proof\resources\views\pages\gallery.blade.php)
```

**I've also tried the following with a negative result:**

```
@foreach ($photos as $photo)
   <img class="img-fluid options-item" src="{{$path}}/{{ $photo['destinationPath'] }}{{ $photo['filename'] }}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

**result:**

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined index: destinationPath (View: C:\Apache24\htdocs\collection\proof\resources\views\pages\gallery.blade.php)
```

any guidance on the right syntax would be much appreciated.

**controller:**

```
class GalleryController extends Controller
{

    function index($coin_id)
    {
        $coin = Coin::select('photos', 'mint', 'year', 'series', 'rating')
            ->where('id', '=', $coin_id)
            ->where('user_email', '=', auth()->user()->email)
            ->first();

        $photos=$coin->photos;
        $path=url('/');

        dd($photos);

        return view ('pages.gallery', compact('coin', 'photos', 'path'));

    }
}
```

Comment: updated my answer, and the reason why you get that error.

Comment: can you make sure the data you posted is correct?

Comment: Just verified.  It's from the DD in the following --from controller:(i added controller function to the post above)

Comment: Here is the data from postgres:   [{"destinationPath":"images\/","filename":"15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-34824.jpg"},[{"destinationPath":"images\/","filename":"15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-89914.jpg"}],[{"destinationPath":"images\/","filename":"15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-30958.jpg"}],[{"destinationPath":"images\/","filename":"15-1-tue-apr-7-2020-130-am-68870.jpg"}]]

Comment: at the end of  the code `]` did not match

Comment: also the code you posted, the end `]` is not matching as well

Comment: wow... you are correct.  thank you for your help--you are awesome.  Not sure how to figure out that bug yet but it's definitely the pointer I needed.  thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here first you are using `@for`, but you end up with `@endforeach`. which one you want to use? `for` loop or `foreach` loop?

```php
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++)
  <img class="img-fluid options-item" src="{{$path}}/{{ $photos[$i]['destinationPath'] }}{{ $photos[$i]['filename'] }}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

if you want to use `foreach`

```php
@foreach ($photos as $photo)
 <img class="img-fluid options-item" src="{{$path}}/{{ $photo->destinationPath }}{{ $photo->filename }}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

The reason you get the error is that `$photo['destinationPath']` is the array syntax. `$photo` is actually `object`. so you need to use `->` to access its property.

Comment: sorry, cut and paste error uploading txt to stackoverflow.  I'd prefer to use @foreach.

Comment: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'destinationPath' of non-object (View: C:\Apache24\htdocs\collection\proof\resources\views\pages\gallery.blade.php)